# Инкапсуляция. Принципы ООП

Tags: ооп, инкапсуляция

Начал изучать объектно-ориентированное программирование. Со всеми принципами разобрался, но не могу до конца осмыслить, для чего нужна инкапсуляция. В моем понимании это контроль входящих данных и более ничего, но разве нет ничего более существенного?

Comment: Человек при ходьбе использует порядка 200 мышц по довольно сложному алгоритму. Но для того, чтобы пойти, вам совершенно не нужно об этом знать. Процесс управления и синхронизации всех этих 200 мышц инкапсулирован в методе "Хотьба"

Answer (score 19):

Более того - инкапсуляция: это самый важный принцип не только ООП, а программирования в принципе. Наследование, и полиморфизм - это строго говоря не принципы вовсе, скорее некоторые свойства ООП-систем связанные с переиспользованием кода.

Почему же так важна инкапсуляция: представьте себе код не учебной задачки, а код огромного проекта, где только кода (со всякими библиотеками) на гигабайт. А теперь представьте, что в этом коде всё крепко-накрепко друг с другом перевязано. Как думаете, возможно будет такой код анализировать в принципе? Даже если предположить что возможно: то очевидно изменение каждого метода будет провоцировать понижение стабильности. ООП старается проецировать реальный мир на код: в реальном мире вода, налитая в чашку не будет проникать в керамику, кнопка от клавиатуры не будет участвовать в вычислениях, а человеческий мозг не будет помогать сердцу толкать кровь. А принцип инкапсуляции - это и есть принцип устранения связей, то есть то, что позволяет объектам не "перемешиваться".

Именно **обособление, которое даёт инкапсуляция - позволяет уложить даже огромные объёмы кода в голову**, разделяй и властвуй - это ещё древняя поговорка для реального мира отлично работает и для мира цифрового. А также дополнительно защищает вас от ошибок: компьютер не перестанет работать, если случайно сломать кнопку от клавиатуры(инкапсулированный код). Простота кода объекта X как-раз измеряется количеством открытых связей между объектом X и другими объектами - то есть если этих связей очень много: то очень проблематично положить объект X к себе в голову, проблематично даже дать объективное название объекту X- так как он даёт о себе слишком много разнородной информации.

Инкапсуляция проявляется не только в `private` и `protected`. Метод класса инкапсулирует в себе алгоритм и переменные. Вы можете не бояться делать неразборчивые четырёхъярусные алгоритмы внутри метода класса, так как программист которому понадобится класс будет смотреть не на содержимое метода, а на название метода. Это тоже инкапсуляция, работает принцип сокрытия - программисту неважно что внутри, при этом он понимает как всё работает. Тоже самое относится к функциям-замыканиям: они для того и созданы, чтобы обособлять внутри себя алгоритм с переменными для его работы. То есть функции тоже работают прежде всего на инкапсуляцию - т.к. переменные внутри функции, алгоритм их использующий, может совершенно не беспокоить того кто использует функцию. И я бы даже сказал, что функции в современном программировании инкапсулируют гораздо больше, чем модификаторы видимости в классах - яркие примеры сплошь и рядом на `JavaScript`.

Подытожу свой ответ - инкапсуляция это почти что то же самое, что и обособление. Именно обособление - ключевая вещь, которая помогает систему любых размеров уложить в голове. Инкапсуляция уменьшает количество связей между объектами - думать о них, и прокручивать в голове механизм их работы становится гораздо проще, разработка ускоряется.
**Разделяй и властвуй.** Однако это верно только для средних-больших проектов, с множеством подключаемых библиотек. На небольшой задаче реальную пользу инкапсуляции увидеть можно только когда пренебрегая использованием функций/классов, у вас образуется слишком большой стек глобальных переменных, от которых голова пойдёт кругом.

Answer (score 9):

Инкапсуляция - сокрытие данных. Приведу простой пример. Допустим у нас есть прямоугольник, у которого поля открыты (модификатор доступа `public`):

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width;
    public int height;
}
```

Вы же можете написать следующий код:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.width = -1;
rect.height = -1;
```

С точки зрения компилятора все отлично, -1 имеет тип `int`, ничего незаконного мы не делаем. Но Вы то понимаете, что так делать нельзя (что означает отрицательная высота?) и хочется как-то избавиться от этой ошибки. Что можно сделать? А можно сделать следующее:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public void setHeight(int value) {
        if(value <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        height = value;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    //Тоже самое с width
}
```

Что изменилось? У поля `height` модификатор доступа стал `private`, то есть теперь за границамы класса мы не можем получить к нему доступ. Но ведь это тоже не дело, мы, скорее всего, захотим использовать это поле у себя в коде. Для этого был добавлен метод (называется геттер) `getHeight()`. Также, добавился метод (называется сеттер), который, собственно, и решает нашу проблему (с отрицательными значениями). Теперь, если попытаться сделать следующее:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.setHeight(-1) ; //IllegalArgumentException!
```

Будет ошибка!

**Таким образом**, мы "скрыли" поля (используя модификатор `private`) и задаем их значение через методы (называемые сеттерами), в которых можем проверять данные на корректность (валидация). Теперь другие программисты (если Вы работаете в команде) или Вы сами не смогут "поламать" Ваш обьект (сделать так чтобы что-то перестало работать). Разумеется, пример приведенный мною, является очень простым. На практике (когда Вы работаете в команде) все не так очевидно. В конце концов, Вы можете просто ошибиться и, допустим, поделить на 0 (это Java сообщит Вам об ошибке, а на C++ программа аварийно завершиться и потом гадай в какой строке из миллиона что-то не так!!!).

Comment: Опять же, в вашем примере мы только проверяем входящие данные, если же они не соответствуют условию, мы обращаемся к обработке исключений. Выходит, ни для чего другого инкапсуляция не используется?

Comment: @VladKvochin, Вы видимо не уловили суть. Давайте еще раз: инкапсуляция - сокрытие данных. Сокрытие фактически и есть обьявление полей с модификатором `private`. Еще раз перечитайте, тем более, что я специально для Вас добавил вывод, чтобы Вам было еще проще понять.

Answer (score 6):

> Инкапсуляция (encapsulation) - это механизм, который объединяет данные
> и код, манипулирующий этими данными, а также защищает и то, и другое
> от внешнего вмешательства или неправильного использования.
>
> (from codenet.ru)

Инкапсуляция нужна для того, что бы пользователь не мог использовать не предназначенный для него функционал. Почитайте Гради Буча "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование
с примерами приложений на С++". У него нормально расписано и примеры интересные.

Система должна быть закрыта, как Ганнибал Лектор в камере. Мы знаем как узнать жив ли он еще и как дать ему покушать. Больше взаимодействовать с ним нельзя. Могут быть последствия.

Очередной апдейт. Компьютерную программу можно рассматривать как систему, состоящую из функционала предназначенного для пользователя и функционала предназначеного для служебного использования. Служебный функционал следует скрывать, что бы не вводить пользователя в недоумение и не дать ему возможности изменить внутреннее состояние системы не подобающим образом.

Comment: За пример с Ганнибалом мои бурные аплодисменты переходящие в овацию! :)

Answer (score 3):

Объект *"знает"* свое состояние, и когда его *"попросите"*, чтобы свое состояние изменил, сделает то так, чтобы его состояние *было всегда консистентным*.

Пример:

- Объект: `Время` в виде *минуты:секунды* вместе с методом `увеличения` *на любые количество секунд*.
- Состояние: `7:42`.
- Просьба: Увеличивай свое состояние на `20 секунд`.
- Новое состояние: `8:02`.

---

Когда бы вы сохраняли минуты и секунды в 2 *независимых* переменных, тогда на *всяком месте программы, где бы вы добавили секунды, должны были опять и опять проверять, если не нужно изменить тоже количество минут* - и могли бы это забыть.

И каждому, кто бы хотел добавить что-то до вашей программы, указать на это.

Answer (score 1):

Как указано в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) с трактовкой термина не все просто. Под ним могут подразумевать механизм ограничения доступа и/или конструкцию языка позволяющую упаковывать данные и методы обработки этих данных. Если по ограничению доступа вам много написали и это достаточно просто для понимания, то с упаковкой у начинающих все плохо и с чистой совестью для каждого поля класса создаются пара `get` `set` методов. В подавляющем большинстве случаев это явный признак того, что имеет место нарушение инкапсуляции. Объект должен **сам** обрабатывать свои данные, а не быть просто контейнером для них. Объект это данные + поведение, в противном случае это не объект в том смысле, который вкладывал в него автор `ООП`. И на мой взгляд это является более важным, чем просто механизм ограничения доступа.